# Why does PDO execute() start a transaction?

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

This is a test snippet from my application:

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".$dbName.";charset=utf8mb4";
$options =
[
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
    PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING
];
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPass, $options);
var_dump($conn->inTransaction());
$sql = "SELECT
    documentTypeID
    FROM documentTypes";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
var_dump($conn->inTransaction());
$result = $statement->execute();
var_dump($conn->inTransaction());
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Why is the third `var_dump` true?  I didn't intend to start a transaction.  My understanding of transactions is that `SELECT` statements don't need or affect them.  What am I missing?

After this happens in my app, I try to `beginTransaction()`, which fails because one has already started.  Checking to see if `inTransaction()` is true before I begin one seems sloppy, but if that's how this is supposed to work, I guess I'll do it.

Comment: You turned off auto-commit. So every query starts a transaction.

Comment: Oh, that's news to me.  I thought since auto-commit was off, no query would start a transaction.  
I actually had auto-commit on before, but turned it off while diagnosing this problem.  I'll try it the other way again...

Comment: Yes, it looks like the problem that led me to ask this question was a much simpler problem with code that I wrote.